# Can't boot (16.04) with Asus PIKE 2008 installed

Tags: boot, nvidia, asus, raid

I've recently built a system based on two Xeon E6-2670s and an Asus Z9PE-D16/2L Motherboard. Things have been working well, but recently I also acquired an Asus PIKE card to enabled the additional SAS ports on the motherboard.

My machine now posts and gets to grub, but once I boot the kernel it eventually just hands and I dont seem to see any really useful boot output on the console. I also have an older nvidia GTX 260 card installed too.

When I get a chance I will probably try booting without the nvidia card, just using the onboard video and also try turning VT-d off.

Anyhow, I'd love any guidance or tips from anyone thats familiar with this hardware. Thanks